# $\beta_k=\sum_{n=k^2}^{k^2+2k}\alpha_n$ where $|\alpha_n|\leq\frac{1}{n}.$ If $\sum\beta_k$ converges then $\sum\alpha_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of reals which satisfies:
> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \space \space :|\alpha_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$.
>
>  
>  Denote $\beta_k = \sum\limits_{n=k^2}^{k^2+2k} \alpha_n$ , for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\sum\beta_k$ converges, then $\sum\alpha_n$ converges.

I observed that the sequence of partial sums of the series  $\sum\beta_k$ is a subsequence of those of $\sum\alpha_n$. Additionally, I see the relation between the assumption regarding $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to the fact that $b_k$ is a sum of exactly $2k+1$ elements of $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
However, I struggle to see how this is actually true (intuitively speaking) since, generally, I could've only deduced that (without the additional assumption about $(\alpha_n)$) if $2k+1$ was bounded, which of course is not.

I'm also curious to understand in what other cases similar assumptions about $(\alpha_n)$ would follow the same conclusion, and hence I hope to get some ideas about the proof of this particular case.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps clarify what you mean by $\sum \beta_k $ being a subsequence of $\sum \alpha_n$. Since neither of these would normally be regarded as sequences, if you mean the sequence $\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}},$ you would need to justify your observation

Comment: @Carlyle I apologize, English is not my first language, I tried again.

Comment: $\beta_k$ actually sums exactly $2k+1$ elements of $(\alpha_n)$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Fixed

Comment: You can fix a general positive integer $n$, generally being between two perfect squares, and note the sum up to $n$ is equal to the sum up to the largest square less than or equal to $n$, plus a minor remaining part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Theorem: Suppose $(j_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of
> natural numbers with $j_1=1,\ (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ and $\ (b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ are sequences
> of real numbers such that: $(i)\ b_k =
>  \displaystyle\sum_{n=j_{k}}^{j_{k+1}-1} a_n,\quad (ii)\
>  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k\ $ converges (to $L\in\mathbb{R}$), and $\ (iii)\
>  \displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} \left( \max_{t\in\{ j_k,\ j_k+1,\
>  \ldots,\ j_{k+1}-1 \}} \left\lvert \sum_{n=j_k}^{t} a_n \right\rvert \right) =
>  0.\quad $ Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\ $ converges to $L$ also.

Proof: Let $L:= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k.\ $ Let $\varepsilon>0.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that

$$ \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{j_{n+1}-1} a_k \right\rvert = \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k \right\rvert < \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} \quad \forall\ n\geq N. $$

Since also, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} \left( \max_{t\in\{ j_k,\ j_k+1,\
 \ldots,\ j_{k+1}-1 \}} \left\lvert \sum_{n=j_k}^{t} a_n \right\rvert \right) =
 0,\ \exists\ K\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that

$$ \max_{t\in\{ j_k,\ j_k+1,\
 \ldots,\ j_{k+1}-1 \}} \left\lvert \sum_{n=j_k}^{t} a_n \right\rvert < \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} \quad \forall\ k\geq K. $$

Now let $\ M = \max\{ N,K \}.\ $ Suppose $\ n\geq M.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ M' \geq M\ $ such that $\ n\in \{ {j_M}',\ {j_M}'+1,\ \ldots,\ j_{M^{'}+1}-1 \}.\ $ Thus,

$$ \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right\rvert = \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{{j_M}'-1} a_k - \sum_{k={j_M}'}^{n} a_k \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{{j_M}'-1} a_k \right\rvert + \left\lvert \sum_{k={j_M}'}^{n} a_k \right\rvert $$

$$ \leq \left\lvert L - \sum_{k=1}^{{j_M}'-1} a_k \right\rvert + \left\lvert \max_{t\in\{ j_{M'},\ j_{M'}+1,\
 \ldots,\ j_{M'+1}-1 \}} \left\lvert \sum_{n=j_{M^{'}}}^{t} a_n \right\rvert\ \right\rvert < \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} + \frac{ \varepsilon }{2} = \varepsilon. $$

This completes the proof.

$$$$

Now suppose $\ \lvert \alpha_n \rvert\ < \frac{1}{n}\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ \beta_k:= \displaystyle\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \alpha_n.\ $ Then,

$$ \max_{ t\in \{ k^2,\ k^2+1,\ \ldots,\ (k+1)^2-1 \} } \left\lvert \sum_{n=k^2}^{t} \alpha_n \right\rvert $$

$$ \leq \max_{ t\in \{ k^2,\ k^2+1,\ \ldots,\ (k+1)^2-1 \} } \sum_{n=k^2}^{t} \left\lvert \alpha_n \right\rvert $$

$$ \leq \sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \frac{1}{n} \overset{*}{\approx} \log\left((k+1)^2\right) - \log(k^2) = 2\log\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right) \overset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0. $$

Now suppose further that $\displaystyle\sum \beta_k\ $ converges.

We can put $\ a_n=\alpha_n,\ b_n = \beta_n\ $ in the theorem and, since all three conditions are satisfied, the result follows.

$*\ $ This can be made more proper with Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I decided to leave this out of the proof to improve readability.

Comment: Let me know if the indices are confusing or if there are any errors in my proof.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One key to problems like this is to consciously focus on the definitions of the terms involved.

- We are trying to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n$ converges. By definition, that means we want to prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N$ exists, where $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n$.
- We are given that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_k$ converges. By definition, that means we know that $\lim_{K\to\infty} T_K$ exists, where $T_K = \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k$.

Of course there's an obvious relation between these quantities, namely that $T_K = S_{K^2+2K}$ for every $K$. What we need to do is to be able to estimate all the $S_N$, not just the $S_{K^2+2K}$. Presumably the assumption $|\alpha_n| \le \frac1n$ should help with that.

With that, let me end with the hint that
$$
T_K - \sum_{n=K^2+1}^N |\alpha_n| \le S_N \le T_K + \sum_{n=K^2+1}^N |\alpha_n| \quad\text{for all } N \in [K^2,K^2+2K].
$$
Can you confirm this hint and then use it to finish the problem?

Comment: Indeed it helps me to understand the general idea more clearly. Though I find it difficult how to technically choose the correct index (.e.g when choosing the $N$ in your hint, we are not sure the corresponding $K$ can be used for the assumption about $(\alpha_{n})$.

Comment: I recommend practicing the argument with specific numerical indices—for example,  you probably understand $S_8$ and $S_{15}$ well in terms of the $T$-sequence; how can you relate $S_9$ and $S_{18}$ to those?